# CSS Recurring nth-child Pattern

Tags: css

Bit of an interesting CSS problem I am trying to figure out to do with patterns.

I want the following to occur:

- LI 1-3 = background green
- LI 4-6 = background red
- LI 7-9 = background blue

Then repeat, so:

- LI 10-12 = background green
- LI 13-15 = background red
- LI 16-18 = background blue

This should repeat infinite times in the same 9 block pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSS selector for `nth-child` to get this.

As your cycle occupies 9 spaces (1-3, 4-6, 7-9), this is `9n` and then add the offset of the item in the list.  For example:

```
ul > li:nth-child(9n + 1),
ul > li:nth-child(9n + 2),
ul > li:nth-child(9n + 3) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Here's a working snippet showing it:

```css
ul > li:nth-child(9n + 1),
ul > li:nth-child(9n + 2),
ul > li:nth-child(9n + 3) {
  background-color: green;
}

ul > li:nth-child(9n + 4),
ul > li:nth-child(9n + 5),
ul > li:nth-child(9n + 6) {
  background-color: red;
}

ul > li:nth-child(9n + 7),
ul > li:nth-child(9n + 8),
ul > li:nth-child(9n + 9) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine</li>
  <li>Ten</li>
  <li>Eleven</li>
  <li>Twelve</li>
  <li>Thirteen</li>
  <li>Fourteen</li>
  <li>Fifteen</li>
  <li>Sixteen</li>
  <li>Seventeen</li>
  <li>Eighteen</li>
  <li>Nineteen</li>
  <li>Twenty</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you may have tried `:nth-child(3n)` but found its not what you want.

Here is what you are after:

```
li{
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  &:nth-child(9n + 1), 
  &:nth-child(9n + 2), 
  &:nth-child(9n + 3){
    background: green;
  }
  &:nth-child(9n + 4), 
  &:nth-child(9n + 5), 
  &:nth-child(9n + 6){
    background: red;
  }
  &:nth-child(9n + 7), 
  &:nth-child(9n + 8), 
  &:nth-child(9n + 9){
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

It looks like you are repeating in groups of 3, but in reality you are repeating in groups of 9. That is because you have 3 groups of 3, i.e. 3x3=9

```
nth:child(9n)
```

will target every 9th element. Now its just a case of incrementing this to handle the first 3, the second 3, and the third 3.